# ECharts - animation after append data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

I have  line-time-series chart (in ECharts). I need to keep a constant number of points, which moves from left to right with new data. However, when I add data using setOption, there is no shift, but each point just changes its position in the y direction.
Can someone please advise me what I'm doing wrong?
This [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dynamic-data2) does exactly what I need. I think I have it the same, but it still behaves differently.

Thank you

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.js"></script>
<div id="app" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;">
<div ref="echart" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ></div> 
<button type="button" @click="onClick"> Push data < /button></div>


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted() {
        this.chart_data=[
            ['2020-09-01 15:14:13.0', 1],
            ['2020-09-01 15:14:14.0', 1.5],
            ['2020-09-01 15:14:15.0', 0.7],
            ['2020-09-01 15:14:16.0', 0.8],
            ['2020-09-01 15:14:17.0', 1.7]
        ]
        this.chart=echarts.init(this.$refs.echart)

        var option={
            color: '#3283bb',
            xAxis: {
                type: 'time',
                splitLine: {
                    show: false
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'value',
                splitLine: {
                    show: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                showSymbol: false,
                type: 'line',
                areaStyle: {
                    opacity: 0.2
                },
                lineStyle: {
                    width: 1.5
                },
                data: this.chart_data,
                hoverAnimation: false
            }]
        }

        this.chart.setOption(option)
    },
    methods: {
        onClick: function() {
            this.chart_data.shift()
            this.chart_data.shift()

            this.chart_data.push(['2020-09-01 15:14:18.0', 2.5])
            this.chart_data.push(['2020-09-01 15:14:19.0', 2.0])

            this.chart.setOption({
                series: [{
                    data: this.chart_data
                }]
            })
        }
    },
})
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Clyde256/b2d4juzt/37/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out the answer directly from the ECharts developers. Therefore, if someone has a similar problem, the solution is as follows:

*ECharts performs animates "shift" if it recognizes part of the old data in the newly added data. Currently, this can be done by adding a unique name to each value. Each value is then an object with a name and value property.*

```
{name: '2020-09-01 15:14:18.0', value: ['2020-09-01 15:14:18.0', 2.5]}
```

I am attaching a modified jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Clyde256/b2d4juzt/44/ from the previous post, where the shift already works.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, that if you are using dataset functionality, you need to name your dimension and then in the series property use the encode block and set `itemId` to any dimension name that has unique values like so:

```
dataset: {
      dimensions: ['value', 'ts'],
      source: [],
    },
```

```
series: [
          {
            name: 'some line',
            type: 'line',
            encode: {
              x: 'ts',
              y: 'value',
              itemId: 'ts',
            },
          },
        ],
```

Then the chart renders with correct 'shift left' animation when new values are added and old ones are removed.